# Issues entering probability distrubution function in matlab

Tags: probability, matlab

I want to enter this function into matlab, but I am in doubt what to do with the infinite spectrum

[image]

My try was this, but the graph looks very wrong
[image]

Comment: What do you need to do with the function in Matlab?  This will change how you need to input it.

Comment: If you just need to see the graph, it looks wrong because you forgot to divide the argument of $\arctan$ by 5: you should have f=1/2*(1+(2/pi)*atan(x/5));   Also, take a smaller interval like $[-20:0.1:20]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @icurays you should use the correct function and range:

```
x = -25:0.001:25;
f=1/2*(1+(2/pi)*atan(x/5));
```

Furthermore you will probably want to get your plot in the right position, so not only plot the function values, but also give the x values as input to your plot function:

```
plot(x,expcdf(f))
```

I do not have Matlab at hand, so there may be a typo somewhere, but it should work like this.